# Changed my IPv4 to ssh into OpenWRT on rpi2 - did dhclient on my host afterwards- Now I have two IPv4 on one NIC - and it works! How?

Tags: ip-address

as described in the title, sorry I wanted to have a specific title and I could not get it specific and short and the same time, I did the following:

1. Flashed a SD Card with OpenWRT to test it on a Raspberry Pi.
2. OpenWRT has dhcp client disabled and puts a static IP in that image that does not correspond to my network IPv4 pattern.
3. So I changed my host IPv4 to 192.168.1.2 in order to connect to 192.168.1.1. That worked.
4. After logout I did dhclient on my host.

Now I have access to all my network devices as before and still can connect to that OpenWRT machine I described above. I only have one NIC on my host system. So I wonder how this can work?

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether *somevalue* brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.2/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.88.88.80/24 brd 10.88.88.255 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 863229sec preferred_lft 863229sec
    inet6 XXX/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 XXX/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr 
       valid_lft 7013sec preferred_lft 1613sec
    inet6 XXX/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply: this is achieved by the ability of the `OS` to assign several `IPv4 addresses` to the same interface and by the use of routing tables and `ARP` - [The Address Resolution Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc826).

When a node (`A`) wants to talk to another node (`B`) knowing initially only the `IPv4 address` of `B`, first it consults its routing tables to find the shortest path to the destination (there might be much more complicated cases, e.g. round-robin policy, but for the simplicity we assume shortest path policy here).
At this point `A` knows two more things: a) which source address to use and b) is a gateway device (`G`) involved into exchange.

Then `A` checks if there is an entry for the `B`'s `IP` address in its `ARP` cache table (if gateway to be used then `A` checks for and uses `G`'s address here and in all subsequent requests).

If the cached entry exists then `A` picks the `MAC` address to send the `IP packet` to from this entry.

If there is no cached information, then `A` broadcasts the `Address Resolution Request` over the `LAN segment` to find out if someone knows the mapping of `B`(`G`)'s IP address into `MAC` address:

```
06:14:26.622107 7a:df:9c:b5:9a:ef > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 192.168.8.145 tell 192.168.8.160, length 28
06:14:26.665609 ac:ed:5c:76:01:38 > 7a:df:9c:b5:9a:ef, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 60: Reply 192.168.8.145 is-at ac:ed:5c:76:01:38, length 46
```

here is the host `192.168.8.160` tries to resolve a `MAC` address of `192.168.8.145`. The response is sent back by any node who has the requested information. Please note, that the request is sent with broadcast `MAC` address (`FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF`) as destination address while the response is sent using unicast `MAC` address of the requester. This is to prevent flooding IP stacks of all nodes connected to the segment with unnecessary information.

Now the node `A` receives the response and populates the `ARP` cache with an entry for `B`, so next time `A` needs to send an `IP packet` to `B` it does not need to query the network again.

This way a node maintains the ability to talk to nodes on different `IPv4 subnets` physically connected to the same `LAN segment` using the same interface.

Note, please, that your `192.168.1.1` node has no idea that your `192.168.1.2` has another, extra IP address assigned to its ethernet interface.

Comment: Ok, I understand that these seems to be a valid process to assign multiple IPv4 to one NIC. That brings me to the point when or why I need to use a virtual bridge adapter? But this is another question I need to think about. So this is a valid answer for my question.

Comment: @superurmel this looks strange that you need bridge, this should work fine without bridge interface at all.